# Stop menu item appearing twice on simple html drop menu

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, menu

This is a very simple question and i'm sure a very simple fix. I have not really used drop menus at all and so have no idea how to change this. All I want to do is to stop the displayed menu item from appearing in the drop down results! So my code is as follows:

```
<form action="">
<select name="menu">
<option value="other">Other blog entries</option>
<option value="other">So you want to shoot a show...</option>
</select>
</form>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSsYU/)

Works fine but when the list is dropped I do not want to display "Other blog entries" as an option within the dropped list. How to I change this to have Other blog entries in the display only and not a drop item? I have googled around and cannot find a solution!

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
<form action="">
  <select name="menu" value="" onchange="var opt=this.options[0];if(opt.getAttribute('role')==='placeholder'&&!opt.selected)opt.parentNode.removeChild(opt);">
   <option role="placeholder" value="" id="hiddenOption">Other blog entries</option>
   <option value="other">So you want to shoot a show...</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

And CSS:

```
#hiddenOption {display: none;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DSsYU/1/

Is this the desired result? :)

Comment: Wow, no wonder I could not do it! I thought this was just me being dumb! that is great and exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you so much, that would have taken me forever to work out.....

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped :) Usually a bit of JavaScript and CSS does the tricks.